# Progress dialog while running computation task in background (AsyncTask)

Tags: java, android

I am very confused, i am trying for two days to make animation on an image while my engine is thinking of a move (this is a game app). I execute the chooseMove() method inside AsyncTask object because it is a little heavy recursive function that may take some time,and also i want to rotate an hourglass image while the engine is thinking. and i tried to do it every way i know:  another AsyncTask, Android's own animation class,handlers etc'.   but no matter what i do it seems that i can't make it work.    if i try to execute two threads at the same time,it only executes one of them, and the same thing happens with android own animation class.    so i tried to use a progress dialog just to see that i am not getting crazy,and guess what..  same problem!   I show the progress dialog in the onPreExecute() ,but the doInBackgroun()  never gets done!  the progress dialog take control over the whole app for some reason.    how should i do it?   i though that the progress dialog is meant for this kind of things.   thx!

EDIT:   this is the code of my async task class.  as you can see, i am showing a progress dialog in the onPreExecute() ,and dismissing it in the onPostExecute.    but the onPost never gets called because the doInBackground() never gets called either.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    activity.setPlaying(true);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        // only for gingerbread and newer versions
        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Thinking...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    int engineWin = board.takeWin(board.getBoard(), engine.getNumberOfEngine());
    int opponentWin = board.takeWin(board.getBoard(), engine.getNumberOfOpponent());

    if(engineWin!=-1){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return engineWin;
    }
    else if(opponentWin!=-1){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return opponentWin;
    }
    else{

        if(engine.isEnginesTurn()&&!Board.checkGameOver(board.getBoard())){
            int[] newBoard = new int[42];
            System.arraycopy(board.getBoard(), 0, newBoard, 0, 42);
            return engine.chooseMove(engine.isEnginesTurn(),newBoard,-500001,500001,0,4).getMove();
        }

        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

}





@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if(result!=-1){

        ballAnimTask = new BallAnimTask(activity,boardView,board,engine);
        ballAnimTask.execute(findSlotNumberByIndex(result));
    }

}
```

this is the recursive chooseMove() i am calling in doInBackground().  before i tried to show the progress dialog,everything worked just fine.  there is no problem with this function or any other function for that matter.   only when i tried to do animations or dialogs at the same time,i got issues.      the chooseMove() is physically on another class and i am only calling it from the AsyncTask.   maybe this is the problem??

```
public Best chooseMove(boolean side,int[]board,int alpha,int beta,int depth,int maxDepth){
    Best myBest = new Best();
    Best reply;
    int num;
    if(Board.checkGameOver(board)||depth==maxDepth){
        myBest.setScore(returnPositionScore(board));
        return myBest;
    }
    if(side){
        myBest.setScore(alpha);
        num = numberOfEngine;
    }
    else{
        myBest.setScore(beta);
        num = numberOfOpponent;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> availableMoves = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    availableMoves = searchAvailableMoves(board);
    for(int move:availableMoves){
        board[move] = num;
        reply = chooseMove(!side,board,alpha,beta,depth+1,maxDepth);
        board[move] = 0;
        if(side&&reply.getScore()>myBest.getScore()){
            myBest.setMove(move);
            myBest.setScore(reply.getScore());
            alpha = reply.getScore();
        }
        else if(!side&&reply.getScore()<myBest.getScore()){
            myBest.setMove(move);
            myBest.setScore(reply.getScore());
            beta = reply.getScore();
        }
        if(alpha>=beta){
            return myBest;
        }
    }
    return myBest;
}
```

Comment: why don't you create your own thread then to update ui in runonuithread. computation can be done in the thread and ui updation on runonuithread

Comment: when i tried to do the animation on another seperate thread,i just couldn't execute the two threads together parallely. only one gets executed and after that the other.  but now,that i see that i got the same problem also with android own animations and progress dialog it make me wonder if i missed something here...

Comment: create two thread not asynctask. and use runonuithread to updateui

Comment: do you think asynctask is the problem here?  why can i at least execute android's own progress dialog implementation right

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform any UI related operation from within an `AsyncTask` you need to call the `AsyncTask` [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) method. This will invoke an `onProgressUpdate` callback in the main UI thread and so you can then safely perform your UI related operations there.

Obviously any code in the `onProgressUpdate` can't block, though, since you are now back in the main UI thread. But you can update a status bar, for example, and then wait for the next `onProgressUpdate` callback before you update it again.

Comment: but the onPreExecute() also run on the UI as far as i know,and it is not the first time i am using a progressDialog while doing something in the doInBackground().  but this time its getting stuck for some reason..not letting the doInBackgroungd() to be executed at all.  i feel that its got something to do with the recursive function.  could it be that if i am calling a certain function from doInBackground()  but the function itself is physically related to another class,than i am actually executing it on the main thread??

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood what you were asking. It would probably help if you added some sample code to your question - preferably a minimal version of the actual code that fails.

Comment: Try replacing the `doInBackground` method with nothing but a `sleep` call. If that works, then start adding sections of the code back one by one until it fails again. If the problem is definitely caused by the `ChooseMove` call, then replace that with nothing and slowly add pieces of it back until it fails. Repeat until you can narrow down the problem to a single line of code if possible.

Comment: I understand what you are saying..but when i am running the chooseMove alone,i get no issues.  the only problem i got is when i am trying to do something else at the same time like a progressDialog or execute another background thread doing some animation stuff etc'.    the only thing i can think of is that maybe even if the chooseMove() gets called from the doInBackground() it still runs on the main thread..and that i am overloading it trying to do some other stuff on the main thread.  but can it be??

Comment: Let's assume that deep down in your code there is a function called by a function that's called by a functions that's called from chooseMove. And that function does something that interacts with the UI or the main thread in some way that causes the background thread to block. The only way you're going to find that code is my narrowing down where it occurs.

Comment: ok.. i got you.  so if i understand correctly,if any of the functions that get called during the chooseMove() method (which is a lot) got something to do with the main thread, than this could be the problem. I will try search for a function like this like you said
but i can't think of a function that do something very meaninful on the main Ui thread.  i mean..i can't avoid changing some parameters and arrays and stuff because than i have to change my whole app

Comment: If you're planning on searching your code for specific UI related calls you may never find anything. It could be something that isn't at all obvious. The easiest way to track down this sort of problem is by commenting out large parts of your code until it works, and then adding small sections back until fails again. Once you know exactly where it's failing you can then try to figure out why. At the very least I hope you commented out the `doInBackground` method like I initially suggested. If that works, that would at least confirm that the `ProgressDialog` isn't directly to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Just for some inspiration, here is the general code format that I have used successfully to show a horizontal progress bar which updates while  a background task is running. I know it doesn't answer your exact question, but I hope it helps you to find your solution.

```
ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;

private void someFunctionThatStartsTheAsyncTask()
{
    new myBackgroundTask.execute(someIntegerArgument);
}

private class myBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(myContext);
        myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        myProgressDialog.setTitle("Doing something in background...");
        myProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        myProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        myProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        myProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        myProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        myProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        int someVariable = params[0];
        boolean success;

        for (whatever loop conditions)
        {
            // some long-running stuff, setting 'success' at some point
            ...

            publishProgress(newPositionForProgressBar);
        }

        return success;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progressPosition)
    {
        myProgressDialog.setProgress(progressPosition[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();

        if (result)
        {
            //doInBackground returned true
        }
        else
        {
            //doInBackground returned false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code :)   i am still trying to think, maybe i got the whole asynctask thing wrong.  maybe i shouldn't call functions that are on outside classes and calling other functions.  maybe the whole code have to be Exclusive for the doInBackgroun().  but it seems unlogical to me.  i think that it i were calling some functions that update the UI in some way,i would be getting an error try to operate them from the doInBackground.